# Colab Google using qiskit Aer

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, qiskit

Here is my code:

```
#!pip3 install qiskit
!pip3 install qiskit-aer
from qiskit import Aer, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister
```

This is the Error I get:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-14-2acb4a3b8d5d> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 !pip3 install qiskit
      3 get_ipython().system('pip3 install qiskit-aer')
----> 4 from qiskit import Aer, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister
      5 
      6 # Load training data

ImportError: cannot import name 'Aer' from 'qiskit' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/qiskit/__init__.py)
```

I use Google Colab. I also used the following:

```
!pip3 install qiskit
and !pip install qiskit
```

And I got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Aer` is no longer part of Qiskit. In order to use the `Aer` module, you should install the `qiskit_aer` package with

```
pip install qiskit-aer
```

(see [qiskit aer getting started](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/aer/getting_started.html))

Once installed, you can import the `Aer` module directly from `qiskit_aer` using

```
from qiskit_aer import Aer
```